# Writing JSON with XSLT

Tags: json, xslt

I'm trying to write XSLT to transform a specific web page to JSON. The following code demonstrates how Ruby would do this conversion, but the XSLT doesn't generate valid JSON (there's one too many commas inside the array) - anyone know how to write XSLT to generate valid JSON?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://bbc.co.uk/radio1/playlist'))
xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(DATA.read)

puts out = xslt.transform(doc)

# Now follows the XSLT
__END__
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/plain"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        [
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[@id='playlist_a']//div[@class='artists_and_songs']//ul[@class='clearme']">
            {'artist':'<xsl:value-of select="li[@class='artist']" />','track':'<xsl:value-of select="li[@class='song']" />'},
        </xsl:for-each>
        ]
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Omit the comma from the line inside the `for-each` and add:

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
```

This will add a comma to each item except the last one.

Comment: IMHO, position() is XSLT's only flash-of-genius feature.

Answer (score 5):

Splitting up your XSLT into separate templates can increase readability.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/plain"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//div[@id='playlist_a']//ul[@class='clearme']" />
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul">
    <xsl:text>{'artist':'</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="li[@class='artist']" />
    <xsl:text>','track':'</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="li[@class='song']" />
    <xsl:text>'}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also, the values of artist and song can break your JSON if they contain single quotes, replacing single quotes could be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Sitecore Item Web API instead? It is available on SDN and is installed as a simple plugin. When it is installed you can use REST to get items back as JSON. It is possible to search for items and you can set security for the individual fields available through JSON. Further on you can actually create, delete and update Sitecore items using REST and JSON.

Comment: Off course, at the time of your question the Item Web API was not available :-)

Comment: Is this comment related to the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837809/writing-json-with-xslt)? If so, what made you think this was a Sitecore question - if not, there must be a bug in SO somewhere and it's getting confused.