# Sitecore: Xslt to JSON?

Tags: json, xslt, sitecore

I have a couple of Sitecore item fields that i need to output as json.
Can i do this with Xslt (1.0)? It is a fairly basic loop and data output in xslt, that i need converted to json.

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: ok .. Have you tried anything on your end? It's a tough job .. starting to code from scratch..

Comment: btw I have a link for you http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' thats for XSLT 2.0 - Sitecore runs XSLT 1.0, so no luck there :-(

Comment: Why not use Sitecore Item Web API instead. It lets you query the Sitecore tree using REST and as a result it outputs JSON. It is available on SDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read through [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837809/writing-json-with-xslt) (and it's on XSLT 1.0). It seems they are trying to do the same thing, and includes a code sample.