# Produce A Json File From XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I'm using xslt to tranform xml to json. My need  is to produce a json outputfile after transform is completed. Is there any way for doing that. It will be more useful.

I have tried with following files.

This is xml file that I used and parsed to json using the xslt style sheet

sam.xml

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<Customers>
<Customer Id="99">
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <Age>39</Age>
    <Address>
        <Street>10 Idle Lane</Street>
        <City>Yucksville</City>
        <PostalCode>xxxyyy</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Customer>
<Customer Id="101">
    <Name>Bill</Name>
    <Age>39</Age>
    <Address>
        <Street>10 Idle Lane</Street>
        <City>Yucksville</City>
        <PostalCode>xxxyyy</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Customer>

</Customers>
```

sam.xsl (xslt sheet used to parse the xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>  
     <xsl:template match="/">{
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
    </xsl:template>  
    <!-- Object or Element Property-->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Array Element -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
        <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Object Properties -->
    <xsl:template name="Properties">
        <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>{
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    }</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Attribute Property -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

index.html (open will show the json output in div tag)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/js/jquery-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/js/jquery.xslt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
     $('#transformResult').xslt("sam.xml","./resources/xsl/SampleXsl.xsl");    
    }); 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="transformResult"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Index.html is just for testing the json output.i have used jquery plugin os xslt.

And I want a json file. I got output in div tag. But my need is to produce json file with the output. Please Help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing JSON with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837809/writing-json-with-xslt)