# XSLT String building with loop

Tags: json, xslt, powerpoint

I am trying to use XSLT to do the following seems like it should be fairly simple but I can not seem to get it.

From:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<updateUserDetails>
    <updateUserInfo>
        <userIdentifier>9999</v1:userIdentifier>
        <firstName>K1</v1:firstName>
        <lastName>T1</v1:lastName>
    <updateUserInfo>
    <updateUserInfo>
        <userIdentifier>9998</v1:userIdentifier>
        <firstName>K2</v1:firstName>
        <lastName>T2</v1:lastName>
    </updateUserInfo>
</updateUserDetails>
```

To:

```
"userIdentifier": "9999"
{
"firstName": "K1",
"lastName": "T1"
}
"userIdentifier": "9998"
{
"firstName": "K2",
"lastName": "T2"
}
```

Comment: Is this JSON output? If so, consider tagging so other SO folks can find it. I know there are many Q/As on XML to JSON conversion. Plus you cannot use an XSLT stylesheet due to different end use formats but must use coding language such a C#, Java, PHP, Python, VB.

Comment: Yes it is a JSON conversion through PowerPoint and have to use XSLT to get the format, the end point communication is taken care of but need to get the submit right, tag updated, thanks.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. You removed prefixes, but not everywhere, plus missing character in XML declaration. Also notice, that without namespaces the XSLT will be different. So it makes sense to post the XML as close to original as possible, including namespaces.

Comment: Actually, JSON doesn't look like well-formed JSON either...

Comment: Please do a search for XSLT + JSON, study the examples and come back if you run into a **specific** problem implementing them.

Comment: But XSLT only handles `.xml` , `.html` and other [SGML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) markup formats, not `.json` extensions. For instance, you have no nodes/attributes in desired output. Unless you use `<xsl:output method="text"...>` to output to text then save as json manually. See this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837809/writing-json-with-xslt).

Comment: OK, disregarding where it is going.  How would I make that XML look like that string.  The issue I have is with moving user Identifier to a different level and not all elements will be present all the time.  For example there are address fields and first or last name may not be there.  It is the formatting I need worked out.  The rest I can take care of.

Comment: @Parfait, why is XSLT not suited? It can easily be done and in fact, it is used often for it with as result language enhancements in XP30, XQ30  and XSLT30 to make it even easier, including `parse-json()`, `json-to-xml()` and `xml-to-json()`, which are, surprise, by en large defined in XSLT itself (because it is so trivial) ;).

Comment: _"The rest I can take care of."_ >> that's good, start there, consider a good tutorial on XSLT (just google, many to find, incl. a PluralSight basics and in-depth course). Once stuck, show us your code with [mcve] and we'll try to help. Note, see also: what can't I ask [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem?

```
<xsl:template match="updateUserInfo">
"userIdentifier": "<xsl:value-of select='userIdentifier'/>"
{
  "firstName": "<xsl:value-of select='firstName'/>",
  "lastName": "<xsl:value-of select='lastName'/>"
}
</xsl:template>
```

You might have slight problems because your input isn't valid XML and your desired output isn't valid JSON, but I expect you can sort that out.